# Perform segue from button in XIB

Tags: xcode, ios5, xib, segue

I'm using storyboards for the most of my project, but i have one UIScrollView that consists of multiple views that are loaded from XIB

I'm stuck on how to perform a segue when a button is clicked in the XIB

What i've done already.

- Added the views to a scroll view
- Added a custom button
- added an IBAcion on the custom button

MainViewController

```
NSString *nibName = @"coverArticleView";
NSArray *nibObjects = [NSBundle.mainBundle loadNibNamed:nibName owner:self options:nil];
coverArticle *pageView = [nibObjects objectAtIndex:0];
pageView.articleTitle.text = ob.Title;
pageView.articleTitle.numberOfLines =0;
// updating some more properties here & designing the scroll view
[coverArticlesScrollView addSubview:pageView];
```

coverArticle.m (class of the XIB)

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"button pressed");
}
```

When the log 'button pressed' is printed so that's working.
But how do i perform a segue when the button is pressed ?

thnx

Answer (score 0):

How about [performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/performSegueWithIdentifier%3asender%3a)?

Comment: performSegueWithIdentifier is not available in the 'coverArticle'-class