# call multiple button in a UITableviewcell

Tags: ios, swift

I have a xib file with 4 buttons and each button has a function which it has to start when clicked. The function has to fetch data and after it has fetched data it should perform a segue. I am only allowed to use a nib which is of type UITableViewCell and show it in a tableview inside a viewcontroller.

Is it possible to get each button to start the required function when tapped in the tableviewcell, if so how do i go about it.

I have looked at questions similar to mine for days and tried all the suggested solutions and they arent working e.g.

[image]

[Show ViewController from XIB-file-Button - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29238560/6516391)

[Perform segue from button in XIB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11259199/6516391)

[Swift - Segue from Button inside a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26143820/6516391)

[Perform segue from button in XIB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11259199/6516391)

[Perform Segue from Xib programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26712758/6516391)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it's pretty simple in the code to have the event passed in the action and then access the index path.

First add the target to your button.

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(someAction(_:event:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Then use this code to start your action.

```
@objc func someAction(_ button: UIButton, event: UIEvent) {
    guard let location = event.allTouches?.first?.location(in: tableView),
        let indexPath = tableView?.indexPathForItem(at: location)
        else {
            return
    }

    // TODO: fetch data

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySegueID", sender: button)
}
```

Also if your data is async, you could use something like PromiseKit.
https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit

Comment: Where does the function sit because my code to fetch data is in the nib class

Comment: You can make a controller object (which inherits from NSObject or nothing) and call it from there.

Comment: like a viemodel?

Comment: If your designing based on MVVM then sure, otherwise you can simply refer to it as a controller.